# Función doble con resultado incorrecto

Tags: funciones, haskell

Tengo esta función extraída como respuesta de este sitio en inglés que verifica si una variable se trata de una cadena

```
esCadenaNumerica :: String -> Bool
esCadenaNumerica ""  = False   
esCadenaNumerica "." = False
esCadenaNumerica xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False
```

A partir de la función anterior, la función `esNumerico` chequea si un dato (de cualquier tipo) se trata de un  número

```
esNumerico :: Show a => a -> Bool
esNumerico x = esCadenaNumerica (show x)
```

Seguidamente defino la función doble, que en primer lugar debería chequear si el valor ingresado es un número y en función de qui esta definición se cumple multiplicar el valor ingresado por el usuario * 2 sino mostrar el valor ingresado por el usuario.

```
doble:: Int -> Int
doble x = if esNumerico(x) then 
           2 * x
          else
           x
```

El programa compila bien, pero la función `esNumerico` no está funcionado.

doble 2
4

(resultado correcto)

doble "4"
(tira error)

Comment: Significa que la función que determina si el valor introducido es numérico o no, siempre devuelve `false`

Comment: No veo el sentido de la función `doble`. El argumento siempre es un número entero, ¿de qué sirve chequear si es un número?. Por otro lado, a la llamada `esNumerico("x")` estás pasando una string `"x"` que, evidentemente, no es un número, por lo que siempre se evalúa a `false` y devolverá  siempre la parte `else` del `if`.

Comment: Si lo que querías es convertir el número entero en una string para comprobar que es un número, estarías complicando la función sin ningún sentido. Explica mejor qué es lo que realmente quieres que haga.

Comment: La función doble tendría que espetar cualquier argumento, por lo que la firma de la función debería ser doble:: a -> Int